# Cannot get properly chunked response using Akka streams

Tags: java, akka-stream, playframework-2.5, chunked

Using the example provided in the [Play! Framework documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaStream#Chunked-responses), I've created a modified version that issues some delayed events, so I could observe them occurring at the same rate in the client side:

```
public Result playExampleDelayed() {
    Source<ByteString, ?> source = Source.<ByteString> actorRef(5, OverflowStrategy.dropNew())
            .mapMaterializedValue(sourceActor -> {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    sourceActor.tell(ByteString.fromString("tick " + i), null);
                }
                sourceActor.tell(new Status.Success(NotUsed.getInstance()), null);
                return null;
            });
    return ok().chunked(source);
}
```

However, using `curl`, we get all the events in a single step, when the source is completed.

Using a different source type I can get the intended behavior:

```
public Result tick() {
    Source<ByteString, ?> source = Source.<ByteString> tick(Duration.create(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS),
            Duration.create(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS), ByteString.fromString("tick"));
    return ok().chunked(source);
}
```

In this case, I'll get in the console one chunk per second.

According to the Akka documentation, I'd expect the first example to work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `Thread.sleep` in your `mapMaterializedValue` call. This is a synchronous call that happens right after you `run()` your stream. Blocking in here (e.g. with a `Thread.sleep`) will block the whole materialization. Therefore, all the messages will be picked up by the actor at the very end of the loop execution.

Bottom line: always steer away from using `Thread.sleep` when using Akka.

On the contrary, `Source.tick` uses a scheduler (async, non-blocking), and is therefore a far more performant, robust and elegant solution.

Comment: The `Thread.sleep` was just a simulation of an "heavy work". Surrounding the `for` cycle with a `CompletableFuture` made the trick. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Correct, that's what it's usually used for. I'll rephrase :)

Bottom line: always steer away from blocking when using Akka.

Comment: I need to access the DB which has a blocking API. The play framework pretty much forces me to use akka streams. What's the way to write it? I want to split the work into multiple DB fetches: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59360044/migrating-play-framework-2-4-chunked-response-to-play-2-5-2-6-akka-stream-source